# How can I avoid duplicate attributes in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make java class to register attributes in a table and without duplicates attributes.

I don't know which method to use.

#### TriggerAttributes.java

```
public class TriggerAttributes extends TableTrigger {

    public void trigger() {
        if (!isEmptyCodeAtlas)
            this.attributesDouble(codeAtlas, Paths._Root_RelationPostale_Attributs._CodeAtlas, "Code Atlas déja utilisé, pas de doublon possible");
        if (!isEmptyCodeEden)
            this.attributesDouble(codeEden, Paths._Root_RelationPostale_Attributs._CodeEden, "Code Eden déja utilisé, pas de doublon possible");
        if (!isEmptyLibelle)
            this.attributesDouble(libelleCourt, Paths._Root_RelationPostale_Attributs._LibelleCourt, "Libellé déja utilisé, pas de doublon possible");
        if (!isEmptyCodeAtlas || !isEmptyCodeEden) {

            Vector<String> list = new Vector<String>();
            if (isEmptyLibelle)
                list.add("Libellé court");
            if (longeur == null)
                list.add("Longeur");
            if (largeur == null)
                list.add("Largeur");
            if (hauteur == null)
                list.add("Hauteur");
        }
        if (!isEmptyCodeAtlas && niveau == null)
            this.Exception = "Le champ Niveau est obligatoire si un code Atlas est utilisé";
    }
    
    private void attributesDouble(Object value, Path xPathValue, String error) {

        String Exception = "test";

        Request request = this.Attributs.createRequest();
        request.setSpecificFilter(new TriggerAttributes.FiltreAttributs(value, xPathValue));
        RequestResult result = request.execute();

        if (result.getSize() > 1) {
            this.Exception = this.Exception + error;
        }
    }

}
```

Please share your ideas.

Comment: Too much code.  Does 'table' mean 'relational database'?  If yes, add unique constraints to the column(s) you need to be unique.  Those are candidate keys.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your code has multiple issues that make us unable to help you. 1. Multiple variables and fields don't exist, e.g. `this.Exception` and `niveau`. 2. variables and fields name should start with lower case character. 3. `String Exception = "test";` - don't shadow a field. 4. `Vector<String> list` is unused. 5. Why do you use `Vector` at all? It's synchronised and you don't need that. 6. Although localisation is fine, variables names in non-English are not helpful to us.

Please have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if im getting the question or not but if you're trying to avoid duplicates in your list then instead of a list it would be best to use a Set / Hashset as this doesn't 
allow for duplicates. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

It wont throw an error if theres a duplicate it just wont be added to the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for indications, i solved my probleme by adding a new methode checking if there is du dupliated attributs and null attributs